# How to control ViewPager change page in Fragment object

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I write a ViewPager with some Fragments. In the Fragment, there are VideoView. At the beginning, the first VideoView will auto play, when the first VideoView finishes, I want change the page of VideoView, so I want call setCurrentItem in Fragment. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use eventbus notice viewpager to next page.
implement toNextPage func

```
void toNextPage() {
    if (viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() >= viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "is end", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I use EventBus and send message to my CustomViewPager from Fragment successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As you've not mentioned the language you're using, I'm gonna answer it for both Java and Kotlin.

- **Java:**

  Create a function in your `ViewPager's` Activity as

  ```
  public void changeViewPagerPostition(int position) { 
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(position); 
  }
  ```

  And call this function it from `Fragment` with passing the postition parameter as

  ```
  ((YourActivity) getActivity()).changeViewPagerPostition(yourPostition);
  //Remember first item is at 0th postition and so on.
  ```

  You can also declare the ViewPager as public static in your `Activity` and can access the ViewPager directly in `Fragment` but this is not the preferred way.
- **Kotlin:**

  In kotlin, it's a bit easy I believe, although you can use exact same way mentioned for Java but I use this way as I also use `ViewPager` for more things:

  Declare the ViewPager as global variable in your `Activity` as

  ```
  lateinit var viewPager : ViewPager
  ```

  Initialize in it `onCreate()` of the `Activity` as

  ```
  viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
  ```

  And use it in fragment and pass your current postition as

  ```
  (activity as YourActivity?)!!.setCurrentItem(yourPosition)
  ```

Now, the moment your video finishes, you can call any of these ways in your `Fragment` to change the `currentItem` of the `ViewPager`.